# Is defining a "ProbableBugException" code smell, paranoia or good practice?

Tags: java

In my Java code, I occasionally run into situations where I have to catch a checked exception from a library function that I'm *pretty sure* can't occur in my use case.

Also, when coding, I sometimes notice that I'm relying on certain inputs from other modules (my own) to have or not have particular features. For example, I might expect a string to be in a certain format etc. In these situations, I would often put in a verification step, although I control the code that send the input myself.

At the moment, I'm working on a quite complex product that I want to be very reliable. Among other things, I want it to collect information from caught exceptions and automatically file bug reports. **For the above two scenarios, I therefore defined an (unchecked) "ProbableBugException", that tells me I made a mistake in the code delivering the input data.**

Is that a) stupid, b) paranoid or c) good practice? This is going to be subjective, I'll put up three wiki answers so we can vote away without rep warping.

**ETA**:
*Thanks to Svend for pointing out that Java has assertions, I didn't realize that. Assertions are actuall pretty much what my question was about, but I only knew them from C and have never used them there.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm thinking that using an [assert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) is what you really want there ("probably bug").

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Java had them. Yes, it's pretty much what I want.

Comment: The problem with assert is that by default is disabled at runtime. While it is a good practice to use asserts it is not all the time the recommend, especially in a library because you may never know if the application will have the assertions enabled. I don't think throwing a special exception in this case can be considered stupid or paranoid.

Comment: Well, explicitly throwing an AssertionError amounts to practically the same as my custom exception and is independent of assertions being enabled. If a library function puts me in a catch block that I never expected to be in, I also find "throw new AssertionError" slightly more readable than "assert false".

Answer (score 2):

It's stupid, because:

- the exception should be much more specific, like InvalidInputException
- you should think harder about the input side, it's likely that it's shaky if you feel you need that kind of exception

Comment: OK...'stupid' might be harsh, but if you control the input, use asserts. That's what they're for. As for checked exceptions from library code, well, you have to remember "It's your fault" - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001079.html . Catch the exception, report it, and then dig in to see what you did wrong.

Comment: Well, in that case, I'm fine with the harshness. :-) I have a tendency to overengineer when I work with Java, that can be pretty hard to fight.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice, because:

- you might have a coworker coding on the input side and the two of you might have misunderstood each other
- if you make a mistake, fixing it becomes trivial
- in situations where the input side is a plugin of some sort, it helps the plugin developers (who might be external) to deliver correct input.

Answer (score 0):

I always expect the unexecpected.

I often have code like this :  ( $div will never be 0 into my code )

```
if( $div != 0 ) {
   $var = $var2 / $div;
} else {
    /*
     * It should never happen
     */   
    throw Exception( 'relevant message' );
}
```

I always protect myself from me and the others

Comment: Any particular reason you don't use assert here?